# Lambda API receiving post body on Postman, but not from angular frontend

Tags: .net, aws-lambda, github-pages

I have built a .NET lambda api that is deployed, and an Angular app served on Github pages. The app works correctly with GET requests, but for some reason, the body of all my POSTs aren't getting through. The error being thrown doesn't mention it being a CORS error. When accessing the same API through postman, everything works perfectly. The following is an example controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SessionController:ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserCommandRepository _userCommandRepository;

    public SessionController(IUserCommandRepository userCommandRepository)
    {
        _userCommandRepository = userCommandRepository;
    }

    [HttpPost(Name = "Login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> IssueJWTAsync(UserInputDTO userInputDTO)
    {
        LambdaLogger.Log(userInputDTO.UserName);
        LambdaLogger.Log(userInputDTO.Password);
        string? jwt = await _userCommandRepository.Login(userInputDTO.UserName, userInputDTO.Password);
        if(jwt == null)
        {
            return StatusCode(401);
        }
        return Ok(jwt);
    }
}
```

When I call from postman, I see the username and password logged in cloudwatch. However, when the same request is made from the pages app, both fields are shown to be empty in the logs. I have a an http interceptor that logs the outgoing requests on the angular app. On the frontend side, the body of the request is appropriately populated. The return error is a 401 error because the session creation obviously fails with empty user and password fields. Is this a pages issue or a lambda issue? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: in case it matters, the following is the frontend code that makes the post request

```
 public loginRequest(userInfo:UserRequest):Observable<string>{
    return this.http.post<string>(routeCreator("Session"), userInfo, {responseType: 'text' as 'json'})
        .pipe(map(x => {
                        if (Object(x) instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                          throw x;
                        }
                        return x;
                        }),
              catchError(errorHandler)
              )
  }
``
```

Comment: How is the post made?

Comment: The post request is created by the angular http client

Comment: The frontend code worked correctly (locally) with a standard .NET asp web api with the same controller code, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. When sending from postman, I was using the form-data mode(I thought that was just a convenience method), but when I started using raw JSON, the sam problem occurred. I added the `[FromBody]` tag to the controller argument and now the function works. My code previously worked with a standard controller based ASP.NET web API, so I don't exactly know what happened under the hood here, but oh well.